# How to use Microsoft bookings API to create a booking with another user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a booking with another user in my organization using the bookings API. However, I am not finding a clear method on how to do that because all the documentation shows are how to create a new booking with the signed-in user (/me). Considering I am the user "x" wanting to make a booking with the user "y". I want the API to access the already existing booking of "y" and make a booking for the user "x". By booking I don't mean the create events in the calendar.

I have referred to this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/booking-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta

however, it only mentions how to create a new business. There is clear or concise documentation on how to access other users existing booking page using the API.

My main question is whether this is possible? Is it possible for user "x" to create a booking to another user "y" with "x" signed in my application which uses the bookings API? If so, please provide some insight on how to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the use case of creating booking appointment with internal user but booking app has a different perspective.

Just to give you a perspective.
MS booking is aimed to work with anonymous customer and a tenant logged in user/business/staff.
So in your appointment request, customer email address will get appointment confirmation/reminder notification.

If you enter your org users email address in Customer Email address field, that person will get email confirmation with a booking appointment.

In another word, for booking customer will be an end user of whom you can bill.

You may consider **calendar event** instead of booking appointment if your internal user is not considered as a customer.
Hope this helps.